# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed exception, on Grails5 only when default dataSource used

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, grails, mysql-connector

I have a grails project which was just upgraded from grails-3.1.6 to grails-5.1.7. After upgrade, I am encountering a frequent Communication link failure issue when querying a MySQL table with default dataSource.

Exception:

> WARNING [http-nio-8088-exec-2] groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand.execute Failed to execute: SELECT id, loa, loa_id FROM crosswalk_table WHERE client_id=:clientId AND update_status=:updateStatus; because: No operations allowed after connection closed. java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

This problem was detected in the deployed environment and was also replicated on the local environment when I turned my PC off for about fifteen minutes.

In my Intellij or Local tomcat console, it prints the exception:

> 14-Dec-2023 00:05:44.096 SEVERE [Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[1285282956:1702488174095]] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.reconnectIfExpired Failed to re-connect connection [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool@7c24cbe8] that expired because of maxAge   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

My project configurations is like:

`application.yml`:

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory'

dataSources:
  dataSource:
      pooled: true
      jmxExport: true
      driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
      properties:
          maxActive: 100
          maxIdle: 25
          minIdle: 5
          initialSize: 5
          maxWait: 10000
          removeAbandoned: true
          removeAbandonedTimeout: 400
          logAbandoned: true
          maxAge: 60000
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 5000
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 15000
          numTestsPerEvictionRun: 3
          testOnBorrow: true
          testWhileIdle: true
          testOnReturn: true
          validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
          validationQueryTimeout: 3
          validationInterval: 15000

  pa:
      pooled: true
      jmxExport: true
      driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
      properties:
          maxActive: 100
          maxIdle: 25
          minIdle: 5
          initialSize: 5
          maxWait: 10000
          removeAbandoned: true
          removeAbandonedTimeout: 400
          logAbandoned: true
          maxAge: 60000
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 5000
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 15000
          numTestsPerEvictionRun: 3
          testOnBorrow: true
          testWhileIdle: true
          testOnReturn: true
          validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
```

I have externalized the hosturl, username and password in another yml file as:

```
dataSources:
  dataSource:
    dbCreate: none
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/everest_dev?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: root
  pa:
    dbCreate: none
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/solu_dev?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: root
```

Code example:

```
@Slf4j
class LoaService {
      def dataSource
  
      def getLoaEditDataD(Map params) {
        String dwClientId = params.get("dwClientId", String.class)
        Sql sqlDAS
        try {
            sqlDAS = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)
            def sqlQuery = "SELECT id, loa, loa_id FROM loa_editor_crosswalk_table " +
                    "WHERE client_id=:clientId AND update_status=:updateStatus;"
            def sqlParams = [clientId: dwClientId, updateStatus: 'Completed', isDeleted: false]
            def result = sqlDAS.rows(sqlQuery, sqlParams)
            return result
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            if (sqlDAS != null) sqlDAS.close()
        }
    }
```

This problem with the communication link failure only reproduces when default dataSource is used; if dataSource_pa is used, the problem is not replicated.

Other project configs:

- Gradle: gradle-7.2
- JDK: 1.8.0
- Tomcat: apache9.0.84/apache8.5.85
- MySQL: 8.0.32
- MySQL Driver: implementation
  "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.19"
- Hibernate: implementation
  "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5" and
  "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.5.Final"

The communication link failure was resolved by using the custom dataSource_pa, and such failures can be avoided when using GORM methods.

The default dataSource is the only problem. I must thus ascertain what might be the cause of this failure.